# C - fwrite dynamic array by a function, pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, fwrite

Im trying to `fwrite()` a dynamic array with a function.
The problem are the pointers inside the `fopen()`.

While successfully `fwrite()` the dynamic array to file, from the main function, when trying to move `fwrite()` to a separate function troubles occur with the pointers. In specific the pointers pointing to the array, which are located inside `fwrite()` within the function.

here is the relevant code.

```
main()
{
...
  unsigned char **pixels_array = NULL; //write this array to file
  allocateArray(&pixels_array);  //prepare array
  fillArray(&pixels_array);
  writeFile(&pixels_array);
  freeArray(&pixels_array); 
...
}

writeFile(unsigned char ***pixels_array)  //param is pointer to double pointer array
{
  ...
  FILE *file = fopen(output_filename, "wb"); //open file
  if (file == NULL)
  {
    printf(ERROR_OPEN_FILE_MSG);
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) //writing row by row of the array to file
  {
    //PROBLEM
    //seg fault when running with current pointers to pixels_array in fwrite()
    fwrite((&(*(*pixels_array)))[i], sizeof(unsigned char) * padded_width, 1, file);
  }
  fclose(file);
}

allocateArray(unsigned char ***pixels_array)
{
  ...
  *pixels_array = (unsigned char**)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned char*)); //image y coord.
  ...
  for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
    //(allocate scanlines) image x coord., no sizeof(unsigned char*) because == 1
    (*pixels_array)[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(width); 
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: why you had to use `(&(*(*pixels_array)))[i]` this complex sequence? can't is be made simpler and more straight-forward?

Comment: Since im restricted to the c89 standard, this solution seems suitable. the allocated pointer array is used to store pixels of an image. the image size is variable.

Comment: since when `c89` ask you to write complex statements for simple jobs? can't you use `pixels_array[i]` instead?

Comment: By the way why using unsigned char ***pixels_array, if the comment says it is pointer to to array of pointers to double? the described comment associative type would be `double ***bar` or am i wrong?

Comment: bad comment, fixed that

Comment: There's no need to pass a `char ***` to `writeFile`.  Make `writeFile` take a `char **` instead, pass in `pixels_array`, and use the same code you had working before you tried to separate it into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a seg fault when dealing with pointers when there are some errors in allocation ,so can yo provide your allocation function too?

And if want to write a row to the file you can simply use:

```
 fwrite((*(pixels_array))[i],rest is same);
```

Comment: i added the allocation, there is still a seg fault with your solution. if its the allocation id be surprised because all worked fine when i wrote the binary file from the main function, without putting frwite into a seperate function. thx

Comment: your solution works: fwrite((*(pixels_array))[i],rest is same); the segmentation fault occured because i was using the skeleton of a old function for fwrite that provide two wrong values for width and height. 
thanks alot to all :)

Comment: it was my first solution so i feel great.happy to be of help:D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing actually wrong in the code you posted, but it is unnecessarily complicated. I would write it as follows:

```
unsigned char **allocateArray (int width, int height)
{
  unsigned char **pa;
  int i;
  int nomem = 0;

  pa = malloc (height * sizeof *pa);
  if (pa) {
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      pa[i] = malloc (width * sizeof *pa[i]);
      if (!pa[i]) {
        nomem = 1;
      }
    }

    if (nomem) {
      for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        free (pa[i]);
      }
      free (pa);
      pa = NULL;
    }

  }

  return pa;
}

void writeFile(unsigned char **pa)
{
  int i;

  FILE *file = fopen(output_filename, "wb");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf(ERROR_OPEN_FILE_MSG);
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    if (!fwrite(pa[i], padded_width * sizeof *pa[i], 1, file)) {
      /* Error */
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char **pixels_array = allocateArray(padded_width, height);
  fillArray(pixels_array);
  writeFile(pixels_array);
  freeArray(pixels_array);

  return 0;
}
```